# C# Facebook SDK - Posting on somebody else's FB wall

Tags: c#, facebook

I've followed the following tutorial on how to post a message on your own FB wall:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsO0G-8idyo

...and I've managed to get that to work 100%. But now I would like to post to somebody else's FB wall but I keep on getting the

```
"Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application" error.
```

-Scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages".
-My application is not in Sandbox mode.
-March 2013 breaking changes have been disabled.

Any idea's what could be wrong here?

Comment: Not sure you can any more, but I would like to know also

Comment: Nothing wrong here. The error message makes it very clear that it's disabled. If you want to know why, maybe you should contact the authors of the SDK.

Comment: Do you think its maybe specific to the FB user that i'm trying to post to or an error in my code?

Comment: I don't know the SDK, but from what I understand the functionality is disabled for everyone by the author.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the Facebook SDK. It's deliberately not allowed to prevent it being abused for spam.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way of doing this via other means? Or has this functionality been disabled completely?

Comment: Nope. There is no way at all of doing this.